# returns wrong result when I use ternary conditional operator

Tags: python

There's a function that returns True if given number is prime and False when the number is not. Here's a bit of code:

```
def isPrime(n):
    ...
    ...
    if (k > 0):
        return False
    else:
        return True


if (isPrime(number)):
    print(number, "is prime")
else:
    print(number, "is not prime")
```

And it works fine. But I want to use ternary conditional operator in the **isPrime** function. So I edited the function like this:

```
False if k > 0 else True
```

And now every given number is considered to be not prime. Where's the error in my code?

Comment: do you have a `return` keyword before that ternary operation? Should be `return False if k > 0 else True`

Comment: no, I don't. That was the answer

Comment: Great! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51441135/3233388) also for another approach (a recommended one)

Comment: How about `not k > 0` or `k <= 0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error in your code is that it doesn't have anything that returns the result of a ternary operator. This makes it automatically return `None` which is treated as `False`.

Just return, no ternary operator is needed.

```
def isPrime(n):
    ...
    ...
    return k <= 0
```

**Edit:**

[Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441102/returns-wrong-result-when-i-use-ternary-conditional-operator#comment89852311_51441102)

```
    return not k > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always return `False` until the number will be greater than 0. Because `False` in your code is at the place of `True result`.

Use this:

```
True if k>0 else False
```

In your case:

```
def isPrime(k):
    return False if k<0 else True
```

Comment: yes, but in your case it will be `False if k < 0 else True`

Comment: this is syntax of ternary in python `{result in case of true result from condition} if {condition} else {this will be returned for false result}`

Comment: currently, what are you doing is returning `False` when `k>0`, and it will only be `True` when your `k` will be equal to the negative number.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like:

```
return n if n<m else m
```

Comment: I have just added the syntax, but according to question we always have to check a single value like return false if k<0 else true.

Comment: fine thanx for the info